# What is the context for multi "References" (object pointers) in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, object

Sometimes I see this in others coding...

```
$object->Something_1->Something_2;
```

I understand pointing and object to a function or variable as such...

```
$object->Something_1;
$object->Something_1();
```

But I don't understand how the multiple object pointers strung together work. I haven't been able to find anything online to explain this, so maybe my terms searched are wrong, but would somebody explain or point me to an article where I can learn this?

I don't know what is required to implement such usage and would like to, to see if it's something I can benefit from in my coding.

Comment: The value of `$object->Something_1` is itself an object. Nothing more, nothing less. Not different from `$array['foo']['bar']`, arrays in arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
$object->Something_1->Something_2();
```

is pretty much the same as this:

```
$temp = $object->Something_1;
$temp->Something_2();
```

All it means is that `Something_1` is itself an object which also has members, in this case the method `Something_2`.  There's nothing special about the syntax.  Anything which resolves to an object can have its members invoked with `->`.  So `$object` resolves to an object, and in this case so does `$object->Something_1`.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it. I made yours the answer because it was the most simple explanation. I also made a small code example I thinks makes it simple to understand as well based off what you told me. If you like maybe you can add that to your answer or something similar. Either way, thanks! @ https://gist.github.com/NoahjChampion/87bc9271dd8c05d110032c05730c962a

Answer (score 3):

Your original code sample can be rewritten as: `$invoice->sender->getName();`

In this code the variable `$sender` has been defined as `public` (in the class, that was used to instantiate the `$invoice` object). This means, that the object's encapsulation is broken. The code also expects, that `$sender` will actually contain an object.

You could improve the encapsulation, by using a getter instead of directly accessing the variable: `$invoice->getSender()->getName();`

But this approach is also considered to be a [code smell](http://wiki.c2.com/?AccessorsAreEvil). It would also make the debugging quite annoying and often lead to violations of [Law of Demeter](http://wiki.c2.com/?LawOfDemeter).

**Such chaining is considered to be a bad practice. I would strong recommend avoid it.**

The only exception, that is commonly seen, is chaining of setters, when working with domain entities. In this case, it would be quite common to see code like this:

```
$invoice
    ->setSender('John Doe')
    ->setReceivedOn(time())
    ->setOrder($data);
```

To achieve it, the methods would be defined kinda like this:

```
public function setSender($sender) {
    $this->sender = $sender;
    return $this;
}
```

This particular usecase is not as bad as others, since the class is not actually changing between `->` chain's links (which is what make the debugging of the first two examples into a nightmare). But I personally would still avoid this approach, since *setters* should not return anything and *getters* should not change state of an object.

**TL;DR**: don't adopt this style of code.

Comment: I'm always using Singleton on construct or initialization instead of `setSender` method you mentioned here. I think debugging it will be way easier than `setSender` method.

Comment: one other thing, you can use `return ($this->sender instanceof SENDER)? true : false;` instead of `return $this;` for `setSender` method. With that it makes more sense.

Comment: @ICE IMHO, the best approach is not to return from *setters* at all, adhering to [**CQS**](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html). As for singletons - they are considered an anti-pattern (watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI) to learn why). As for passing dependencies in the constructor - I personally prefer to only use constructor to inject **mandatory** dependencies, and, unless you are using [DDD](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/179133.Domain_Driven_Design), setters are perfectly fine for altering entity's state.

Comment: Thanks for the further context surrounding this and coding standards and video! Appreciate it! Always good.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, this happens when one object, stores one or more other objects as properties.

For example:

```
class Car 
{
    public string $name;
    public Engine $engine;
}
class Engine
{
    public $someProp;
}
```

if you have a car in a variable, you could access the property of the engine like so:

```
$car->engine->someProp;
```

(assuming that the car is initialised and so is the engine in the car)

Comment: Hi. Can you declare a class reference in a string like that? Like public Class_Name ? I tried with your code and got the unexpected string error. Thought I understood what you mean, wondering if there is an easy way to do something like that. To declare a class on the class level rather than the class function level.

Comment: @NoahjChampion Oh, the datatypes are for php 7+ only, you can remove the datatypes (string and Engine) if you are using an older version, they were mostly there to illustrate anyways